# Find the last row in a data frame that meets certain criteria

Tags: r, select, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to refer to a pevious row in my data frame that has one column value in common with the 'current row'. Basically, if this would be my data frame

```
 A  B   D    
 1  10      
 4  5       
 6  6       
 3  25      
 1  40
```

I would want D(i) to contain the B value of the last row for which A has the same value as A(i). So for the last row that should be 10.

Comment: Could you update with the expected output?

Comment: Your example appears to have no rows that would satisfy that test so the answer would trivially be all be NA's.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(dat))) {
    try(dat$D[i] <- dat$B[tail(which(dat$A[1:i-1] == dat$A[i]),1)],silent=TRUE)
}
```

Results:

```
> dat
  A  B  D
1 1 10 NA
2 4  5 NA
3 6  6 NA
4 3 25 NA
5 1 40 10
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="A,B,D
1,10
4,5
6,6
3,25
1,40")
```

Comment: the NA's is not what you want I guess? ...   last row for which A has the same value as A(i) is the row itself when no match...

Comment: @jebsel I commented on the OP's post to show the expected output, but didn't respond.  So, we cannot be sure what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! The NA's shouldn't be a problem. My problem for now is that it's a pretty long dataset so the loop takes a while.

Comment: @MelissaVanderheyden You're welcome... For speed, how do akrun's answers compare?

Comment: To be honest, I tried yours first and couldn't immediately find 'dplyr' or 'data.table' (probably cause I'm not exactly a genius in R :) ..), so I stopped trying. The speed didn't matter in the end since I could just run it once and include the new column in my dataset.

Comment: Ok well, don't forget to upvote/accept (green checkmark) the answer you went along with! Cheers! Dominic

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>% 
    group_by(A) %>% 
    mutate(D=lag(B))
#  A  B  D
#1 1 10 NA
#2 4  5 NA
#3 6  6 NA
#4 3 25 NA
#5 1 40 10
```

Or

```
library(data.table)#data.table_1.9.5
setDT(df1)[, D:=shift(B), A][]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L), B = c(10L, 5L, 6L, 
25L, 40L)), .Names = c("A", "B"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Don't know why, but I couldn't find 'dplyr' or 'data.table'. But thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: @MelissaVanderheyden  You may need to install the packages and load those.

Comment: I know, I just couldn't find them in the list or when I used the help function, or '??'.

Comment: You can install the packages by `install.packages("dplyr")`.  For the devel version of `data.table`, check  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: @Arun Thank you for all the edits. The `[[1L]]` was unnecessary

Comment: Akrun, it was necessary, but not anymore with the recent commit. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29954483/559784).