# Odd Behavior of shift() function in data.table v1.9.5 (R)

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the current development version of `data.table` (v1.9.5), largely because it boasts the wonderful built-in `shift()` function.

I've noticed that, when trying to group statements within a `data.table` call--one of which being a call to `shift()`--I get some funky behavior from it:

```
library(data.table)

foo = data.table(x = c(1, 5, 6 ,2, 9, 8))

foo[, y := {
        delta = c(NA, diff(x));
        lag = shift(x, n = 1L, fill = NA);
        list(delta/lag)}]
```

The above attempt at adding `y` throws the following error:

```
Error in delta/lag : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

So I check what I'm getting by just creating `delta` and `lag` without trying to interact them at all:

```
foo[, c('delta', 'lag') := 
      list(c(NA, diff(x)),
           shift(x, n = 1L, fill = NA))]
foo
   x delta               lag
1: 1   NA  NA, 1, 5, 6, 2, 9
2: 5    4  NA, 1, 5, 6, 2, 9
3: 6    1  NA, 1, 5, 6, 2, 9
4: 2   -4  NA, 1, 5, 6, 2, 9
5: 9    7  NA, 1, 5, 6, 2, 9
6: 8   -1  NA, 1, 5, 6, 2, 9
```

If I separate out the calls, I can get exactly what I want:

```
foo[, delta := c(NA, diff(x))]
foo[, lag := shift(x, n = 1L, fill = NA)]

foo
   x delta lag
1: 1   NA   NA
2: 5    4    1
3: 6    1    5
4: 2   -4    6
5: 9    7    2
6: 8   -1    9
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

EDIT: As Pascal points out, the error in my initial example is a result of the fact that `shift()` returns a list.

Comment: The output of `shift` is a list, not a vector.

Comment: I understand this. But that fact does not explain (at least to me), the difference between the case in which I call  `shift()` within a group of statements and when I call it alone. What about the output being a list should affect this?

Comment: Try `c(1,2,3,4) / list(c(1,2,3,4))` to see what happens.

Comment: You are certainly right, and I see that the output being a list should throw the error in my first example. However, why does the output being a list cause the difference between the second and third examples I give (i.e. where I just try to create `delta` and `lag`)? I've edited the question to reflect your point about the lists--thanks for that.

Comment: Probably `:=` coerces to a vector type.

Comment: I think this makes for a strong argument for `shift` to return a vector instead of a single-element list. I suggest [adding a FR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/new).

Comment: @Pascal OK, that's a good point and certainly explains the behavior.
@eddi Indeed. At least for me, I've bumped up against this a few times already. I can see when `shift()` returning a list could be useful as well, though. Perhaps one should be able to specify the output type. Or, as I assume you meant, it just returns a vector in the single-element-list case only.

Comment: @thagzone I think it should return a vector when it returns a single-element list now, and a list in all other current cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [recent commit in v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/359ccf0ab6fa88f349c94a3cd54d0b88ff1568b1), `shift()` returns vector on vector input and `length(n) == 1`. That is, when the *answer* is a `list` of length 1, we return a vector, for convenience. This allows us to do:

```
DT[, col := shift(val, type = "lead")] # or "lag"
```

and

```
DT[, col := valA + shift(valB, type="lead")] # or "lag"
```

In both cases, a *vector* is returned and the `RHS` of `:=` when atomic, is wrapped with `list()` internally for convenience, and this gives expected behaviour.

This closes [#1127](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1127).