# locate final row in group based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a very large dataframe (~ 4.4m records) that records responses to surveys.  The data is grouped by the id variable and the desired output is
like so:

```
read.table(header = TRUE, text = "month id  request response    dlq
201101  A01 Y   1   0
201102  A01 N   0   0
201103  A01 N   0   0
201104  A01 N   0   0
201105  A01 N   0   0
201106  A01 N   0   0
201107  A01 N   0   0
201108  A01 Y   0   1
201109  A01 N   0   1
201110  A01 N   0   1
201111  A01 N   0   1
201112  A01 N   0   1
201201  A01 Y   1   0
201202  A01 N   0   0
201203  A01 N   0   0
201204  A01 Y   0   1"
```

I would like to create a variable, dlq, that is binary dependent upon the value of the request and response variables.  I would like the dlq column to meet the following conditions

1. If request = "Y" and response = "1", then dlq = 0.
2. If request = "Y" and response = 0, then dlq = 1.
3. If request = "N" and response = 0, lookup most recent month (largest value of month, which is an integer here) where request = "Y".  If response = 0 in this month, then dlq = 1.

The first are simple enough with an ifelse statment.
The problem comes with the third condition.

In the example above, for month 201109, dlq = 1 because request = "N" and response = 0 and the most recent month where request = "Y", 201108, response = 0.  Similarly for months 201110 - 201112.

Based on this ([Find the last row in a data frame that meets certain criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328174/find-the-last-row-in-a-data-frame-that-meets-certain-criteria)) I tried the following to no avail:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(dlq = ifelse(lag(request) == "Y" & response = 0, 1, 0))
```

I know there is a clunky way to do this using only `ifelse` statements. I know to use `group_by` from dplyr to group the data, but I don't know how to execute the above condition cleanly via dplyr or otherwise.  There are tens of thousands of IDs that I need to do this for. I would imagine a `max(irm)[condition]` command may work but I don't know how.

Comment: Your condition requires a marker for the end of the year yet you do not mention it explicitly. Create a `year` column to group by.

Comment: @PierreLafortune thanks. I'm not sure how a year column would make this possible. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: man you should format your question better. I just cant understand the condition you wanna have.. use `this` a bit dude

Comment: @Noobie just changed formatting.  is this better?  thanks.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(gr=cumsum(request=="Y")) %>% mutate(dlq = 1*(response[1]!=1))`